# Suppress calendar audible reminders at night? (HTC M10)

Tags: calendar

By default, when an all day event is set for, say, Tuesday, at 11:50 PM on Monday, your phone goes "ding" to remind you.

If you phone is your alarm clock, and by your bed, you have now been woken up in the middle of the night, for nothing.

How to control/manager?

Comment: What phone are you using?

Comment: @RyanNoles Fair call. HTC M10 (and OP updated)

Comment: What do you mean by "calendar audible"? I know there is an app called audible. Can you send me a screenshot?